# Add to array without echoing index

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell, scripting

I'm adding items to an array called `$MissingIps` using the following command

```
$MissingIps = @("")
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$ExistingIps = $MissingIps
if ($lbips -notcontains $awsip){
    $MissingIps.Add("$awsip")
}
```

On execution, PowerShell automatically echos the index position, and I'm struggling to hide that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the work:

```
$MissingIps = @("")
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$ExistingIps = $MissingIps
    if ($lbips -notcontains $awsip){
        $MissingIps.Add("$awsip") | out-null
    }
```

Comment: other possibilities are `[void]$MissingIps.Add("$awsip")` and (but uglier) `$null = $MissingIps.Add("$awsip")`

Comment: @MickyBalladelli: yup. or we can redirect that to `$MissingIps.Add("$awsip") >> $null`

Comment: @RanadipDutta Thanks. Your original solution did the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the suggested methods of suppressing the unwanted output: don't use an `ArrayList` collection in the first place. It's the `Add()` method of that class that generates the output. If you use a regular array you can append without output being generated:

```
$MissingIps = @()
if ($lbips -notcontains $awsip){
    $MissingIps += $awsip
}
```